# parsing cifar-10 and changing the imgs to HSV

Tags: python, image-processing, hsv

I'm reading the cifar-10 dataset with this code and want to find a way to change it HSV. I tried putting the data and labels lists outisde the functions but I got this error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment`

How can I take out those lists, so that I can change to HSV and then to a histogram of the dataset.

```py
import pickle
import numpy as np
from os.path import join
from os import listdir
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import struct as st

class DataReader:

    def __init__(self,root_dir,type='cifar-100'):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.type = type

    def get_dict_from_pickle(self):
            self.train_dict = unpickle(join(self.root_dir,'train'))
            self.test_dict = unpickle(join(self.root_dir,'test'))

    def get_train_data(self):
        if self.type == 'cifar-100':
            self.get_dict_from_pickle()
            data = np.array(self.train_dict[b'data'])
            lbls_sub = np.array(self.train_dict[b'fine_labels'])
            lbls_class = np.array(self.train_dict[b'coarse_labels'])
            return data,lbls_class,lbls_sub
        elif self.type == 'cifar-10':
            #data = []
            #labels = []
            print("Reading")
            for file_ in tqdm(listdir(self.root_dir)):
                if file_.split('_')[0] == 'data':
                    dict = unpickle(join(self.root_dir,file_))
                    data.extend(dict[b'data'])
                    labels.extend(dict[b'labels'])

            return np.array(data),np.array(labels),None
        elif self.type =='mnist':
            return self.read_mnist()

    def get_test_data(self):
        if self.type == 'cifar-100':
            self.get_dict_from_pickle()
            data = np.array(self.test_dict[b'data'])
            lbls_sub = np.array(self.test_dict[b'fine_labels'])
            lbls_class = np.array(self.test_dict[b'coarse_labels'])
            return data,lbls_class,lbls_sub
        elif self.type == 'cifar-10':
            data = np.empty(shape=(0,3072))
            labels = []
            for file_ in listdir(self.root_dir):
                if file_.split('_')[0] == 'test':
                    dict = unpickle(join(self.root_dir,file_))
                    data = np.vstack((data,dict[b'data']))
                    print(data[data.shape[0]-1])
                    labels.append(dict[b'labels'])
            return np.array(data),np.array(labels),None

    def reshape_to_plot(self,data):
        if self.type == 'mnist':
            return data.reshape(data.shape[0],28,28).astype("uint8")
        return data.reshape(data.shape[0],3,32,32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("uint8")

    def plot_imgs(self,in_data,n,random=False):
        data = np.array([d for d in in_data])
        data = self.reshape_to_plot(data)
        x1 = min(n//2,5)
        if x1 == 0:
            x1 = 1
        y1 = (n//x1)
        x = min(x1,y1)
        y = max(x1,y1)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(x,y,figsize=(5,5))
        i=0
        for j in range(x):
            for k in range(y):
                if random:
                    i = np.random.choice(range(len(data)))
                ax[j][k].set_axis_off()
                ax[j][k].imshow(data[i:i+1][0])
                i+=1
        plt.show()

    def plot_img(self,data):
        if self.type !='mnist':
            assert data.shape == (3072,)
            data = data.reshape(1,3072)
            data = data.reshape(data.shape[0],3,32,32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("uint8")
        elif self.type == 'mnist':
            assert data.shape == (28*28,)
            data = data.reshape(1,28,28).astype('uint8')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
        ax.imshow(data[0])
        plt.show()

def unpickle(file):
    import pickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict
```

Comment: You could use OpenCV. `image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`

Comment: but how do i get to that point is what am i having difficulty with ?

Comment: i added it to the data reader file but is giving me this error" TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'" do you know what that error is? i stuck it here:

Comment: elif self.type == 'cifar-10':
            data = []
            labels = []
            print("Reading")
            for file_ in tqdm(listdir(self.root_dir)):
                if file_.split('_')[0] == 'data':
                    dict = unpickle(join(self.root_dir,file_))
                    data.extend(dict[b'data'])
                    labels.extend(dict[b'labels']) 
                    data  =  cv2 . cvtColor ( data ,  cv2 . COLOR_RGB2HSV )

Comment: Try `data = data.astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: no ,it doesnt like it. i tried it as a loop too but it said" 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'" .i tried it as data[i] and it gave me this error::TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" . ifeel like i m so close its driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

here is waht i did at the end and it worked
          """
           from keras.datasets import cifar10
           import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
           import cv2

```
       (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
       for i in range(0,50000):
           hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(x_train[i] , cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
           hue ,  sat ,  val  =  hsv_image [:,:, 0 ],  hsv_image [:,:, 1 ],  
           hsv_image [:,: , 2 ]
       import numpy as np

       plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
       plt.subplot(311)                             #plot in the first cell
       plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
       plt.title("Hue")
       plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(hue), bins=8)
       plt.subplot(312)                             #plot in the second cell
       plt.title("Saturation")
       plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(sat), bins=4)
       plt.subplot(313)                             #plot in the third cell
       plt.title("Luminosity Value")
       plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(val), bins=2)
       plt.show()
```